# Como criar um pop-up avisando que o script chegou ao fim?

Tags: r, windows

Gostaria de exibir na tela um **pop-up** notificando que o código acabou de rodar.

O único script que possuo, segue abaixo, é o que abre uma janela de comando.

```
system('CMD /C "ECHO O seu script chegou ao fim! && PAUSE"', 
        invisible=FALSE, wait=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, sua resposta e uma possibilidade.

Outra e usar o pacote [rpanel](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpanel/rpanel.pdf). Para isso, voce vai precisar ter instalado o tcl/tk e o pacote BWidget. Depois, dentro do `R`, faca:

```
install.packages("rpanel")
```

Agora voce pode fazer algo como:

```
rp.messagebox("Popup usando rpanel", title="Titulo criativo")
```

que no meu pc vai gerar a seguinte janela:

[image: Popup gerado pelo codigo acima]

Detalhe que esse popup vai bloquear a sessao.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era o que eu precisava!

Comment: Otimo :) Voce pode marcar a reposta que mais te agradou como 'aceita', entao :)

Answer (score 3):

Outra solução é utilizar o pacote tcltk. Esse pacote vem instalado já no R, embora não apareça na lista de pacotes do CRAN.

```
require(tcltk)
tkmessageBox(title = 'Exemplo tcltk', message = 'Operação concluída!', type = 'ok')
```

Assim como ocorre no pacote rpanel, a sessão vai ser bloqueada. Caso não queira bloquear, da para usar uma progressbar, do pacote utils.

```
 invisible(winProgressBar(title = "Concluido!", label = "Operação concluída!", initial = 1))
```

Se o objetivo é chamar a atenção, também pode usar o `alarm()` para emitir um som.

Comment: Que interessante! 
Quem diria que havia esta funcionalidade neste pacote de base!
Obrigado!